# Q: TSQL - Add missing year and month gaps in data?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a requirement to fill in the missing time gaps in the data and populate the Cnt column with 0 for any of gaps. Do I need to use a calendar table for this?

The results of my query are already aggregated, I just need to add the gaps.

```
select name 
       ,YR 
       ,MO 
       ,[Cnt]
from dbo.OON
```

Current Output:

```
Name | YR | MO | Cnt
Kelly | 2014 | 1 | 197
Kelly | 2014 | 3 | 200
Kelly | 2014 | 5 | 300
Kelly | 2015 | 2 | 100
Kelly | 2015 | 3 | 50
Kelly | 2015 | 6 | 70
```

Desired Output:

```
Name | YR | MO | Cnt
Kelly | 2014 | 1 | 197
Kelly | 2014 | 2 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 3 | 200
Kelly | 2014 | 4 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 5 | 300
Kelly | 2014 | 6 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 7 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 8 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 9 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 10 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 11 | 0
Kelly | 2014 | 12 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 1 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 2 | 100
Kelly | 2015 | 3 | 50
Kelly | 2015 | 4 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 5 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 6 | 70
Kelly | 2015 | 7 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 8 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 9 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 10 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 11 | 0
Kelly | 2015 | 12 | 0
```

Comment: Yep, I normally do this with a calendar table. You could recursively generate one at query time, but best option is to create a persistent one and store it in your data warehouse. If you are looking to visualize this, Power BI would a good option, you could generate the calendar in DAX using `CALENDARAUTO()`.

Comment: Here is a good article: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is an ad-hoc tally table

```
Declare @OON table (Name varchar(25),YR int,MO int,Cnt int)
Insert Into @OON values
('Kelly' , 2014 , 1 , 197),
('Kelly' , 2014 , 3 , 200),
('Kelly' , 2014 , 5 , 300),
('Kelly' , 2015 , 2 , 100),
('Kelly' , 2015 , 3 , 50),
('Kelly' , 2015 , 6 , 70)

Declare @PerBeg date = '2014-01-01'
Declare @Months int  = 24

Select B.Name
      ,Yr=Year(A.D)
      ,MO=Month(A.D) 
      ,Cnt=IsNull(C.Cnt,0)
 From (Select Top (@Months) D=DateAdd(MM,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)),@PerBeg) From  master..spt_values) A
 Cross Join (Select Distinct Name from @OON) B
 Left  Join @OON C on B.Name=C.Name and Year(A.D)=C.Yr and Month(A.D)=C.MO
```

Returns

```
Name    Yr      MO  Cnt
Kelly   2014    1   197
Kelly   2014    2   0
Kelly   2014    3   200
Kelly   2014    4   0
Kelly   2014    5   300
Kelly   2014    6   0
Kelly   2014    7   0
Kelly   2014    8   0
Kelly   2014    9   0
Kelly   2014    10  0
Kelly   2014    11  0
Kelly   2014    12  0
Kelly   2015    1   0
Kelly   2015    2   100
Kelly   2015    3   50
Kelly   2015    4   0
Kelly   2015    5   0
Kelly   2015    6   70
Kelly   2015    7   0
Kelly   2015    8   0
Kelly   2015    9   0
Kelly   2015    10  0
Kelly   2015    11  0
Kelly   2015    12  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a permanent calendar table, or you can get away with a normal Numbers table. Either way it is more preferable solution to having build a recursive cte. However, if it is a one off report you can easily get away with a simple CTE, like per the below:

```
;with n as (
  select 1 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM n WHERE n < 20),
years as (
  select 2013 + n.n as [year] from n where n < 3),
months as (
  select 0 + n.n as [month] from n where n < 13)
select r.name, years.[year], months.[month], coalesce(r.Cnt,0)
from years cross join months
left join dbo.OON r on years.[year] = r.[YR] and months.[month] = r.[MO]
order by 1,2,3
```

In the query above you may wish to use the initial value for the `years` cte and the number of year as parameters

Comment: A recursive CTE will perform much less efficiently than the tally table solution that John posted above. Note this excellent article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/